# Correct use of "#" in string concatenation

Tags: ruby

I wrote this piece of code but not sure why it doesn't print the second sentence, it just prints the first part of it which is "Some string concat is like".
I was expecting to see the rest of the sentence from TalkToMe method too.

```
object1 = Object.new

def object1.TalkToMe
  puts ("Depending on the time, they may be in one place or another.")
end

object1.TalkToMe

puts "Some string concat is like " #{object1.TalkToMe} "
```

Comment: Get rid of the unbalanced `"` in the center of that string. The way it currently is, the `#` is starting an "end of line comment".

Answer (score 1):

First, `TalkToMe` should be `talk_to_me` per convention. Second, just return the string, don't use `puts` as it will get evaluated first, and then the string 'Some string...' will get evaluated on a separate line.

Your original question:

Change

`puts "Some string concat is like " #{object1.TalkToMe} "`

to this

`puts "Some string concat is like #{object1.TalkToMe} "`

The syntax highlighting shows that `#{object1.TalkToMe}` is being treated as a comment.

Comment: ok thanks took out the typo of " that was in the middle...but still doesn't print that sentence in continuation of its left side

Comment: @BDotA Did you remove `puts` from `TalkToMe`?

Comment: I also tried that..then it didn't even print the first life part

Answer (score 1):

It should do, but don't end the string.

Replace `puts "Some string concat is like " #{object1.TalkToMe} "` with `puts "Some string concat is like #{object1.TalkToMe} "`

notice the removal of the " in the middle of the sentence